# Why doesn't this work? Create a password protected directory in Cpanel

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a password protected directory with Cpanel, yet once I have added the required code to .htaccess it won't authorize?

Seems to be working yet it won't authorize with the password I created...

Comment: have used this code...

AuthType Basic

AuthName "Restricted Files"

AuthUserFile xx/passwd/

Require valid-user

Comment: AuthUserFile xx/passwd is definitely pointing to a file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthUserFile xx/passwd/
```

Looks like that's pointing to a directory and not a file. Did you actually create the htpasswd file? If so, AuthUserFile should be pointing to that.

Comment: sorry wasn't a solution, but have noted and made an edit to my question... thanks!